# flutter unable to load svg resource

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using the flutter_svg (version 0.10.3)package to load svg in my app. but it shows me an error saying that it is unable to load the resource.
here is my code

```
static final Map<Gender, String> _genderImage = {
Gender.female: 'assets/images/gender_female.svg',
Gender.other: 'assets/images/gender_other.svg',
Gender.male: 'assets/images/gender_male.svg'
};
Widget icon = Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: _leftPadding(context)),
    child: SvgPicture.asset(
      _assetName,
      height: _iconSize(context),
      width: _iconSize(context),
    ));
```

this is the error:
      Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: assets/images/gender_male.svg

Comment: Have you added them to the `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: no but I do not think it is necessary with the package that I am using

Comment: Pretty sure it is :-)

Comment: yes you were right. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding your assets to the *`pubspec.yaml`* is necessary, because [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#specifying-assets) uses the [*`pubspec.yaml`*](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec) file, located at the root of your project, to identify assets required by an app.